# Load specific certificate in Java from worklight

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a worklight project that has an adapter which connects to the services to grab the response.

It uses the worklight keystore that we have created for our project which has the cert required to connect to the backend (cert name : *.company.com) and the keystore (myproject.p12) has the cert in it:

```
ssl.keystore.path =  /was85/.../myproject.p12.
ssl.keystore.pass = Pass
ssl.keytore.type = PKCS12
```

once I get the response back from the adapter, inside it I have URI that I need to use to grab an image from the web services and convert it to base64.

I'm use a custom Java code to accomplish this:

```
package com.company.myProject;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ImageEncoder {
    public final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ImageEncoder.class.getName());
    public static String getImage(String imageUrl)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        String imageDataString = "";
        URL url = null;
        URLConnection con = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(imageUrl);
            logger.info("url     "+url);
            con = url.openConnection();
            logger.info("con     "+con);


            InputStream input = con.getInputStream(); 
            logger.info("input   " + input);

            byte[] bytes = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
            logger.info("bytes   " + bytes);
            input.close();
            imageDataString = encodeImage(bytes);
            logger.info("imageDataString   " + imageDataString);
            return imageDataString;


        } catch (MalformedInputException malformedInputException) {
            malformedInputException.printStackTrace();
            imageDataString = malformedInputException.toString();
            logger.info("MalformedInputException malformedInputException   " + imageDataString);
            return ("exception while reading the imag <" + imageDataString + ">");
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
            imageDataString = ioException.toString();
            logger.info("IOException ioException   " + imageDataString);
            return ("exception while reading the imag <" + imageDataString + ">");
        }


    }

    public static String encodeImage(byte[] imageData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 base = new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64(
                false);
        return base.encodeToString(imageData);
        // return
        // org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageData);
    }
}
```

However, the Java code once it opens the connection it complains about the certification (*.company.com) and gives this error:

```
The signer may need to be added to local trust store "/was85/profiles/node1/config/cells/cell_was/ecommerce_trust.p12" located in SSL configuration alias "DefaultSystemProperties" loaded from SSL configuration file "System Properties".  The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: "PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=AddTrust External CA Root, OU=AddTrust External TTP Network, O=AddTrust AB, C=SE is not trusted; internal cause is: 
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error".
```

And after investigating  it is checking the JVM trust store and not our project trust store.

To resolve this issue I have three options:

1. Add the root cert which is (AddTrust) to myProject.p12 and not my
   leaf cert (*.company.com) which is not accepted.
2. Add the leaf cert (*.company.com) to the JVM keystore
   (ecommerce_trust.p12) which is not acceptable as we have another app
   running on the same JVM and it will get access to the leaf cert.
3. Make a trustManager in my java code to get the project p12 and not
   the JVM one which has the following code:

   ```
       try {
           url = new URL(imageUrl);
           logger.info("url     "+url);

       KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
       trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("/was85/resources/security/ecommerce_gr_mobile.p12"), "Pass".toCharArray());

       TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
       tmf.init(trustStore);
       TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();

       SSLContext sslContext = null;
       sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
       sslContext.init(null, tms, new SecureRandom());

       HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
       HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
       logger.info("con     "+con);
       //con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);

       InputStream input = con.getInputStream(); 
       logger.info("input   " + input);

       byte[] bytes = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
       logger.info("bytes   " + bytes);
       input.close();
       imageDataString = encodeImage(bytes);
       logger.info("imageDataString   " + imageDataString);
       //return imageDataString;


   } catch (MalformedInputException malformedInputException) {
       malformedInputException.printStackTrace();
       imageDataString = malformedInputException.toString();
       logger.info("MalformedInputException malformedInputException   " + imageDataString);
       return ("exception while reading the imag <" + imageDataString + ">");
   } catch (IOException ioException) {
       ioException.printStackTrace();
       imageDataString = ioException.toString();
       logger.info("IOException ioException   " + imageDataString);
       return ("exception while reading the imag <" + imageDataString + ">");
   } catch (KeyStoreException keyStoreException) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       keyStoreException.printStackTrace();
       imageDataString = keyStoreException.toString();
       logger.info("keyStoreException   " + imageDataString);
   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException noSuchAlgorithmException) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       noSuchAlgorithmException.printStackTrace();
       imageDataString = noSuchAlgorithmException.toString();
       logger.info("noSuchAlgorithmException   " + imageDataString);
   } catch (CertificateException certificateExceptione) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       certificateExceptione.printStackTrace();
       imageDataString = certificateExceptione.toString();
       logger.info("certificateExceptione   " + imageDataString);
   } catch (KeyManagementException keyManagementException) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       keyManagementException.printStackTrace();
       imageDataString = keyManagementException.toString();
       logger.info("keyManagementException   " + imageDataString);
   }
   return imageDataString;
   ```

   }

which is not working and I'm getting this error:

```
[9/2/15 13:40:09:512 EDT] 0000021d ImageEncoder  I   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>trustStore loaded <<<<<<<<<<java.security.KeyStore@f1c4b946
[9/2/15 13:40:09:512 EDT] 0000021d ImageEncoder  I   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>tmf init <<<<<<<<<<javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory@4d3fb9ab
[9/2/15 13:40:09:513 EDT] 0000021d ImageEncoder  I   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>tms init <<<<<<<<<<[Ljavax.net.ssl.TrustManager;@c76fa980
[9/2/15 13:40:09:513 EDT] 0000021d ImageEncoder  I   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>sslContext  <<<<<<<<<<
[9/2/15 13:40:09:570 EDT] 0000021d ImageEncoder  I   con     com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.e:https://domain.company.com/wps/wcm/connect/e77f32e8-906f-445f-b198-e3b77cb0e786/logo90x40.gif?MOD=AJPERES&CACHEID=e77f32e8-906f-445f-b198-e3b77cb0e786
[9/2/15 13:40:09:676 EDT] 0000021d ImageEncoder  I   IOException ioException   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Answer (score 0):

Worklight server uses the keystore defined by "ssl.keystore.*" to create SSL connection between adapter and backend server configured in adapter's XML file, so if you have custom java code with your own connection you should to set your own SSL context as you do in your example above. It is the right way.
The reason of the error might be the keystore "/was85/resources/security/ecommerce_gr_mobile.p12" doesn't contain the cert of the images server.
I suggest to create separate kestore and use it from adapter's java code. Put into it all certs of the servers you want to reach from adapter's java code.

Comment: Thank you. The issue was I need to add con.connect(); after opening the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding:

```
con.connect();
```

The complete code will be:

```
           KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            File key = new File ("/was85/resources/security/ecommerce_gr_mobile.p12");
            trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(key), "Pass".toCharArray());
            logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>trustStore loaded <<<<<<<<<<" + String.valueOf(trustStore) );



            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(trustStore);
            logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>tmf init <<<<<<<<<<" + String.valueOf(tmf));
            TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();
             logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>tms init <<<<<<<<<<" + String.valueOf(tms));
            SSLContext sslContext = null;
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
             logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>sslContext  <<<<<<<<<<");
            sslContext.init(null, tms, new SecureRandom());

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.connect();
            logger.info("con     "+con);
            //con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);

            InputStream input = con.getInputStream(); 
            logger.info("input   " + input);

            byte[] bytes = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
            logger.info("bytes   " + bytes);
            input.close();
```